# VIM: Show PHP function / class in command line?

Tags: php, vim, ide, ctags

Is there any way to show the current PHP function or class name in the VIM command line? I found a plugin for showing [C function names in the status line](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=610) but it does not work for PHP and in any case I prefer the command line be used to save valuable vertical lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

While looking for something completely unrelated in TagList's help I've just found these two functions:

```
Tlist_Get_Tagname_By_Line()
Tlist_Get_Tag_Prototype_By_Line()
```

Adding this in my statusbar works beautifully:

```
%{Tlist_Get_Tagname_By_Line()}
```

Also, did you read the Vim Wiki? It has a [bunch](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1454) [of](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1296) [tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_current_function_name_in_C_programs) trying to adress the same need. There is also [this (untested) plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3197).

**ENDEDIT**

If you are short on vertical space maybe you won't mind using a bit of horizontal space?

[TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) and [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) both show a vertical list of the tags used in the current buffer (and other opened documents in TagList's case) that you can use to navigate your code.

However, I'm not particularly a fan of having all sorts of informations (list of files, VCS status, list of tags, list of buffers/tabs…) displayed at all times: being able to read the name of the function you are in is only useful *when* you actually need to know it, otherwise it's clutter. Vim's own `[{` followed by `<C-o>` are enough for me.

Comment: Thanks, I already do `[{ ^O` in combination with `scrolloff=3` to see the context. However often when I search large files I need to know where each search result is, and I cannot `[{ ^O` for each search result and line numbers do not provide enough information. I really do need the info made available. Likewise, TagList and TagBar don't fit my usecase either, though I have tried TagList in the past.

Comment: @dotancohen, did you find a solution? See my comment for some more ideas.

Comment: Thanks, romainl, I am playing around with [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1296) that you mentioned, trying to get it to fit my needs. The original (and my improvement) suffer from a bad bug and I've been killing hours with it. I'll get this thing working and it looks like the bounty is yours! Thanks.

Comment: Cool. If you manage to smash that bug, make sure to make your fork available somewhere.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just posted the bug [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728199/why-does-this-function-skip-on-line-63) as even making a reduced test case is proving maddening beyond my ability. But I already see that once the bug is squashed that this is the right way to go about it, so I'm already marking you with the bounty. Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about PHP, and I'm not trying to step on anyone's toes, but having looked at some PHP code I came up with this function which I think takes a simpler approach than the plugins that have been mentioned.

My assumpmtion is that PHP functions are declared using the syntax `function MyFunction(){}` and classes declared using `class MyClass{}` (possibly preceded by `public`). The following function searches backwards from the cursor position to find the most recently declared class or function (and sets `startline`). Then we search forward for the first `{`, and find the matching `}`, setting `endline`. If the starting cursor line is inbetween `startline` and `endline`, we return the `startline` text. Otherwise we return an empty string.

```
function! PHP_Cursor_Position()
    let pos = getpos(".")
    let curline = pos[1]
    let win = winsaveview()
    let decl = ""
    let startline = search('^\s*\(public\)\=\s*\(function\|class\)\s*\w\+','cbW')
    call search('{','cW')
    sil exe "normal %"
    let endline = line(".")
    if curline >= startline && curline <= endline
        let decl = getline(startline)
    endif
    call cursor(pos)
    call winrestview(win)
    return decl
endfunction

set statusline=%{PHP_Cursor_Position()}
```

Because it returns nothing when it is outside a function/class, it does not display erroneous code on the statusline, as the suggested plugin does.

Of course, I may well be oversimplifying the problem, in which case ignore me, but this seems like a sensible approach.

Comment: Thank you Prince, I am testing it now! I suppose for C I can add int, void, and such to the search terms. Just so you know, php classes cannot be preceded with `public` though functions can. I'll report back in a few minutes.

Comment: I updated the search line to this: `^\s*\(static\|public\|private\)\=\s*\(static\|public\|private\)\=\s*\(static\|public\|priva    te\)\=\s*\(function\|class\)\s*&\=\w\+` in order to allow for [reference functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) and the `static` and `private` keywords. Thank you. I am sure that you noticed that I had already awarded the bounty, but I do appreciate you showing me this approach.

Comment: Glad to help - I certainly wasn't bounty-hunting, I just wanted to demonstrate another method. I don't think my function will work well for C, because starting the line with `int`, `void`, etc, could match variable declarations instead of functions.

Comment: I suppose that one could `#define static int`, that would sure make the file fun for coworkers to edit! And I knew that you weren't bounty hunting, but rather genuinely helpful. I've seen your posts on other VIM questions that I browse. Thank you!